# Per-file (ideally per-section) clang-format style override

Tags: c++, clang-format

I would like to mark part of a file with something like:

```
// clang-format -style="{ SomeSetting: NewValue }"

...

// clang-format -style="{ SomeSetting: OldValue }"
```

that would override the global settings in the root `.clang-format` file. If not possible, specific formatting a single file would also do as I could work around by isolating the section that requires the specific formatting in its own file. I have a git pre-commit hook that does the formatting on staged files as well as IDE plugins that run `clang-format` on their own, but I don't want to have to mark specific files and specific settings in either of these places.

The best I can do now is to format the file with the custom settings, put `// clang-format off`, `// clang-format on` guards around the section and revert the settings back, which is not sustainable in the long term. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is currently (clang 13) not possible, but is certainly a nice feature to add to clang-format.

[Current documentation on Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) states nothing about entering style options in code. As you said, the closest we can get is using `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on` hints.