# How to Change clang-format Rule for a Specific Code Section?

Tags: clang-format

Is it possible to change a clang-format rule for a code section? I know that you can add a comment to disable formatting completely for a section via `// clang-format off`, but is it also possible to change a specific rule?

```cpp
enum class Foo {
    // clang-format AlignConsecutiveAssignments: Consecutive
    ABC = 0,
    X   = 1
};
```

My overall goal is to align the equal signs in an enum, but not in the rest of the code. With `AlignConsecutiveAssignments: Consecutive`, clang-format aligns variable assignments as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, overriding styles for a section of code isn't possible.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61992807)

You could try organizing your project to use different .clang-format's, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24010669).